# Density of k-th order statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

I know that the k-th order statistic density for the uniform distribution is given by:

$f_{(k)}(y) = \frac{N!}{(N-k)!(k-1)!} t^{k-1}(1-t)^{N-k}$.

This is the density if the $N$ samples are sorted in an ascending order. If the samples are ordered in a descending order instead, I assume the proper density to use would be:

$g_{(k)}(y) = \frac{N!}{(N-k)!(k-1)!} t^{N-k}(1-t)^{k-1}$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I suppose this is correct by just substituting $k = N-k+1$.